# StringBuilder sometimes results in mangled lines

Tags: java, csv, stringbuilder

We have a Java application running which processes large amount of data and then writes it to CSV files. We have noticed that around 2% of the lines written are mangled and we have no idea why.

We use the following function for writing the lines:

```
static void writeLineToCSV(List<String> fields, Writer csvWriter) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.size() - 1; i++) line.append(fields.get(i)).append(",");

    line.append(fields.get(fields.size() - 1)).append("\n");
    csvWriter.write(line.toString());
    csvWriter.flush();
}
```

Which results in lines which are mangled as follows:

```
2018-09-21T23:00:11.555Z,1537570811000,-7900,0.57642,39,0.57585,...
2018-09-21T23:00:11.917Z,1537570811000,-7900,0.57642,39,0.57585,...
2018-09-21T23:00:14592322,0.57377,-100,0.57644,1178.59788311,0.57375,...
2018-09-21T23:00:10.041Z,1537570810000,-4691.50311435,0.576,...
2018-09-21T23:00:10.041Z,1537570810000,-4691.50311435,0.576,...
```

Notice how in the third line, for some reason, the first and second field are mangled together with the separating comma gone without a trace.

EDIT: for completion's sake, the schema of the CSV file is: `Instant.toString(), timestamp (long), BigDecimal, ..., BigDecimal`

Comment: Interesting, but how could we reproduce the issue? What does the `List<String>` contain? How do you open/print the resulting file?

Comment: Your `List<String> fields` is presumably wrong.

Comment: i could not see the "mangled" fields . the third line does not  look different.

Comment: I added the schema for the CSV file. @Michael, well if that's true, then why is the separating comma gone?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod the second field, the time stamp, is mashed together with the first field, the instant string.

Comment: It looks to me like multithreaded access gone wrong

Comment: @user1870238 If the string that you enter pass the method has *already concatenated the fields* then there would be no separating comma. This is not magic. It can't just "not work". I don't even understand what fields you think are concatenated. Every line you've shown has six fields.

Comment: I guess there are strange characters in the `fields` that mangle the result when printed. Check the CSV file as binary in a hexadecimal viewer.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is in the `listed` code rather than where `List<String> fields` is created ???